# pic18f flooding serial with zeros when reset

Tags: microcontroller, serial, rs232, matlab

I'm connecting a pic18f4520 to the pc via serial (and then use Matlab). I used the max232 level converter and the echo test worked fined. However when I reset the pic it floods the connection with zeros: I use `s.BytesAvailable` in Matlab and it is zero at first until I reset the pic and it starts increasing until it reaches the max buffer size. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Posting the code for both reading the input in Matlab and sending the output from the PIC would allow us to *answer* your question rather than simply speculating about possible causes of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You have a firmare bug.

As spearson said, the PIC's TX pin should have a pullup to avoid glitches at powerup.  If you initialize pins before turning on the UART peripheral, then set the LAT bit high before setting the TRIS bit to 0.  This will keep the line high until the UART is enabled, which should take over at that point.

However, all that only deals with short glitches at startup.  If you are getting sustained characters after the initialization phase, then you have a firmware bug.  What that bug is of course we can't say.  You may have messed up the UART handler, or maybe higher level code is screwing up and constantly sending some byte.

Take a look at the TX line coming out of the PIC with a scope and see what exactly is being sent.  That might give a clue as to where the code is messing up to cause it.  For example, if it looks like a valid framed character, then the UART driver is probably OK and higher level code is bad.  If it looks like a sustained break, then the UART driver is screwed up, or possibly the whole processor is being reset periodically.  The latter could be due to any number of bugs, including inattention to the watchdog timer.

### Soapbox:

Instead of throwing up your hands and saying "it's broken", *think* about what must be happening for you to see the symptom you see.  Keep digging down each layer to get more information.  Putting a scope on the TX line should have been a obvious thing to do before asking anyone for help.

MATLAB is not a good debug tool because you don't know what kind of high level processing it might perform on the serial port.  You want something that shows you low level serial port information.  Once that is working, you can go back to MATLAB to check out passing higher level data.

What have you done to debug your firmware?  Putting the RealIce or any of its poorer cousins on the PIC and stepping thru the code is another obvious thing to do.  This again should have been one of the first things you did before asking anyone for help.

Comment: Easy tiger. Give him a chance.

Comment: @Rocket: He's had a chance for nearly a month. He hasn't been back since 7 hours after posting the question, so it doesn't look like it's going to ever happen. Another drive-by poster, apparently.

Comment: Strange, so why has this question suddenly resurfaced ?

Comment: @Rocket: I think questions with no accepted answer get occasionally bumped by a bot. Note that the new activity was from "community", which is the bot's name. I guess it's to try to get open issues resolved, but it doesn't work with drive-by posters that are long gone.

Comment: Yeah, prolly it should get closed.

Comment: @Rocket: I don't see a reason to close it, especially since it has receive 2 answers.  However, bumping it when the OP hasn't been back for nearly a month is kindof silly too.

Comment: @OlinLathrop your soapbox comment is exactly why I find it so difficult to find junior people to bring on and grow my business. (Younger especially) people seem all too eager to give up and assign blame rather than wonder about the problem and TRY things to see if they can at least isolate the cause, let alone find a fix. I tell my kids that I'll help them without issue no matter how long it takes as long as they're genuinely trying. Once they give up, I'm not going to try to pull them along to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to bias the Tx pin with a resistor.  When the PIC starts, the pin is floating which is causing unwanted transitions.

Here is a test to try, hold the PIC in reset and connect with Matlab and see if you get the zeros.  Close Matlab and start the PIC and let it initialize the serial pins.  After that connect with Matlab again.  If there are no zeros then it is a hardware problem.